# DateTime::createFromFormat(): Call to a member function format() on bool

Tags: php, datetime

I understand that the issue is in my format string, I'm just having a little trouble figuring out exactly what it should look like.

I am using a form which is sent directly to my php script via the action="" (instead of via javascript in onsubmit). I am using a date input which ends up formatting the date like the following random example:

```
2020-09-15T15:07
```

My php with the format looks like this:

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d*H-i", $_POST["registrationDeadline"]);
echo "<h1>" . $date->format("Y-m-d") . "</h1>";
```

I assume the issue is something to do with the letter `T` in the date, I assumed that `*` would allow me to skip over that. I have also tried `"Y-m-dTH-i"` but I don't think I'm actually supposed to use the T there since that is a reserved formatting character.

Comment: There is colon between the hour and the minutes, instead of hyphen: `$date = DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d*H:i", $_POST["registrationDeadline"]);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is colon between the hour and the minutes, instead of hyphen:

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d*H:i", $_POST["registrationDeadline"]);
```

Comment: Ahh thank you, I knew I was missing something trivial. Needed some fresh eyes